# MySQL Insert Cast

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

I have tried to Insert a value into a table in MySQL but I can't make it work. I am using the following queries:

```
INSERT into articulo values (32,'Sala',CAST('$10,000.45999' AS DECIMAL(10,5)),40.2399,200.2399,3,'kid 3');
```

MySQL shows the following error:

```
1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1292 Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: '$10,000.45999'
```

And it shows the following into the table:

[image: Inserted values into table articulo]

Of course I created the table 'articulo' before:

```
CREATE Table articulo
(
 id_art int NOT NULL,
 nom_art varchar (25) DEFAULT 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 prec_art decimal (10,5) DEFAULT 0.000,
 peso_art decimal (10,5),
 existencia float,
 color_art int, CONSTRAINT chk_color1 CHECK (color_art between 0 and 20),
 um_art varchar (10) DEFAULT 'DEF_PZA',
 primary key (id_art)
);
```

I have seen many examples for Casting but all of them use the cast function under a select 
statement.

Any idea how I can do in order to perform what I want?

I want to store $10,000.45999 into the table as a decimal value.
This would be 10000.45999

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert the value by fixing up the number.  For your case, this should work:

```
INSERT into articulo 
    SELECT 32, 'Sala',
           CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE('$10,000.45999', ',', ''), '$', '') AS DECIMAL(10,5)),
           40.2399, 200.2399, 3, 'kid 3';
```

Strictly speaking, the `cast()` is not necessary, but I like to avoid implicit conversions -- these can lead to hard-to-detect problems.

As a note:  it is a good idea to include the column list in the `insert` statement.

Comment: Great Gordon Linoff! Could you just tell me what does CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE('$10,000.45999', ',', ''), '$', '') AS DECIMAL(10,5)) mean? Thank you very much!

Comment: @MichVellve . . . It removes the characters that would cause the conversion to fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use commas or the dollar symbol in your value in that query.

You could rewrite your query as:

```
INSERT into articulo values (32,'Sala',CAST('10000.45999' AS DECIMAL(10,5)),40.2399,200.2399,3,'kid 3');
```

However you don't need to cast your value as a decimal if your column is already well defined as `DECIMAL(10,5)`.

Simply write:

```
INSERT into articulo values (32,'Sala',10000.45999,40.2399,200.2399,3,'kid 3');
```

Comment: Is there any chance that if a user introduced $10,000.45999 or 10,000.45999 MySQL could "Cast" the number into the table? Thanks for your help Sébastien

Comment: No, MySQL will not clean-up this input automatically. Anyway you **must** sanitize your user input no matter what. Don't let user input be written directly to your database.

Comment: Great! I thank you very much Sébastien. I also think that we must filter what the user types and not just let it be written into the DB. One simple solution. Thanks again!